# The criteria for two abelian extensions to be embedded

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Learning class field theory I found this theorem, but I can't prove it or find the solution. I'll be glad to any help.

> Let $L$ and $M$ be abelian extensions of $K$. $L \subset M$ if and only if there is a modulus $\mathfrak m$, divisible by all primes of $K$ ramified in either $L$ or $M$, such that 
>   $$
> P_{K,1}(\mathfrak m)\subset \ker(\Phi_{M/K,\mathfrak m}) \subset \ker(\Phi_{L/K,\mathfrak m}).$$

$\Phi_{M/K,\mathfrak m}$ - is Artin map for modulus $\mathfrak m$.
$P_{K,1}$ is a subgroup of the group of fractions ideals, generated by principal $\alpha \mathcal O_K$-ideals, where $\alpha$ satisfies $\alpha \equiv 1 \pmod{\mathfrak m_0}$  and $\sigma (\alpha) > 0$ for every real infinite prime $\sigma$ dividing  infinite part of $\mathfrak m.$

It's quite easy to prove that $L \subset M$ implies $$
P_{K,1}(\mathfrak m)\subset \ker(\Phi_{M/K,\mathfrak m}) \subset \ker(\Phi_{L/K,\mathfrak m}).$$
But I don't know how to prove another implication.

Comment: The compositum of class fields corresponds to the intersection of the associated ideal groups.

Answer (score 0):

The way I know how to answer this question involves works with ideles rather than ideals.  As long as $P_{1,m}$ is contained in the kernel of the Artin map $I(m) \rightarrow Gal(L/K)$, the global norm index inequality tells you that this kernel is exactly $P_{1,m} \mathfrak N_{L/K}(m)$, where $\mathfrak N_{L/K}(m)$ is the group of norms from $L$ which are relatively prime to $m$.

From an approximation argument (for example found in Lang) what you get is a well defined Artin map on $\mathbb{I}_K$ (the ideles of $K$) to $Gal(L/K)$ whose kernel is $H_L := K^{\ast}N_{L/K}(\mathbb{I}_L)$.  Similarly you get an Artin map on $\mathbb{I}_K \rightarrow Gal(M/K)$ whose kernel is $H_M := K^{\ast} N_{L/K}(\mathbb{I}_M)$.  The containment of kernels of ideals translates to a containment of kernels of ideles: $$H_M \subseteq H_L$$ Without assuming any containment of $H_M, H_L$, you can check that the kernel of the Artin map on the composite field $LM$ is the $H_M \cap H_L$.  Since in this case $H_M \cap H_L = H_M$, we have by the global norm index equality that $$[ML : K] = [\mathbb{I}_K : H_M \cap H_L] = [\mathbb{I}_K : H_M] = [M : K]$$ so $ML = M$, or $L \subseteq M$.  I left out a lot of details.

You may be able to work out the corresponding argument just within the ideals, but ideles are really a better way to organize the abelian extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this was asked long ago, but I had the same question and I couldn't find an answer online.

Here is my solution:

Let $r_{M/\tilde{L}}:\text{Gal}(M/K)\to\text{Gal}(\tilde{L}/K)$ be the restriction map.
As in the first part, we have $r_{M/\tilde{L}}\circ\Phi_{M/K,\mathfrak{m}}=\Phi_{\tilde{L}/K,\mathfrak{m}}$.
This implies
$$\ker(\Phi_{\tilde{L}/K,\mathfrak{m}})=\Phi_{M/K,\mathfrak{m}}^{-1}(\ker(r_{M/\tilde{L}}))=\Phi_{M/K,\mathfrak{m}}^{-1}(\text{Gal}(M/\tilde{L})),$$
and therefore
$$\Phi_{M/K,\mathfrak{m}}(\ker(\Phi_{\tilde{L}/K,\mathfrak{m}}))=\text{Gal}(M/\tilde{L})=H$$
since $\Phi_{M/K,\mathfrak{m}}$ is surjective by Theorem 8.2 (Artin Reciprocity).
We thus conclude that the subgroups $\ker(\Phi_{L/K,\mathfrak{m}})$ and $\ker(\Phi_{\tilde{L}/K,\mathfrak{m}})$ both contain $\ker(\Phi_{M/K,\mathfrak{m}})$, and are mapped to $H$ under $\Phi_{M/K,\mathfrak{m}}$.
This implies, by the correspondence theorem for subgroups, that $\ker(\Phi_{L/K,\mathfrak{m}})=\ker(\Phi_{\tilde{L}/K,\mathfrak{m}})$.
Then the uniqueness part of Theorem 8.6 shows that $L=\tilde{L}\subseteq M$, which concludes the proof.

Comment: You posted an identical answer [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4759197/).  Please do not do this.  If one answer addresses more than one question, post the answer *once*, then flag the other question(s) as duplicate(s).