# Abelian extensions and the Artin map

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I'm trying to understand a proof of the following:

> Let $L$ and $M$ be Abelian extensions of $K$ (a number field). Then
> $L\subset M$ if and only if there is a modulus $\mathfrak{m}$,
> divisible by all primes of $K$ ramified in either $L$ or $M$, such
> that
>
> $$P_{K,1}(\mathfrak{m}) \subset \ker(\Phi_{M/K,\mathfrak{m}}) \subset
>  \ker(\Phi_{L/K,\mathfrak{m}}).$$

(Here $P_{K,1}(\mathfrak{m}) = \{\alpha\in K^*\mid \alpha\equiv^*1\mod{m}\}$, and $\Phi$ is the Artin map.)

Note: this is the same question as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389301), $\color{red}{\text{but I'm asking for clarification of a particular proof that does not involve ideles }}$
$\color{red}{\text{(as the proof in the linked question does).}}$

The proof I'm looking at goes as follows:
First assume $L\subset M$, and let $r:\text{Gal}(M/K)\to \text{Gal}(L/K)$ be the restriction map. Choose a modulus $\mathfrak{m}$ for which both $\ker(\Phi_{L/K,\mathfrak{m}})$ and $\ker(\Phi_{M/K,\mathfrak{m}})$ are congruence subgroups modulo $\mathfrak{m}$. Since $r\circ \Phi_{M/K,\mathfrak{m}} = \Phi_{L/K,\mathfrak{m}}$, it follows that $$\ker(\Phi_{M/K,\mathfrak{m}}) \subset
 \ker(\Phi_{L/K,\mathfrak{m}}).$$
That part is clear.

For the other direction, suppose that the inclusion condition in the statement holds, and let $\ker(\Phi_{L/K,\mathfrak{m}})\subset I_K(\mathfrak{m})$ correspond to $H\subset \text{Gal}(M/K)$ under the Artin map $\Phi_{M/K,\mathfrak{m}}$. Then $H$ corresponds to some intermediate field $K\subset\tilde{L}\subset M$. $\color{red}{\text{The first part of the proof, applied to }}$
$\color{red}{\tilde{L}\subset M}\color{red}{\text{, shows that }}$ $\color{red}{\ker(\Phi_{\tilde{L}/K,\mathfrak{m}})=\ker(\Phi_{L/K,\mathfrak{m}}).}$ Then uniqueness proves that $L = \tilde{L}$, and we are done.

The sentence in red is the one I'm confused about. I just don't see how the first part of the proof is relevant. One can use it to show that $\ker(\Phi_{M/K,\mathfrak{m}}) \subset
 \ker(\Phi_{\tilde{L}/K,\mathfrak{m}})$, but then what? Why does that imply that the kernels are equal?

Comment: @reuns For clarification, did you intend that to explain the red statement, or is it a different method of seeing the result?

Comment: I think this is part of the idea behind your proofs. Look at the subfield $F \subset M$ such that for each prime $\mathfrak{p}$ of $K$ , $f(\frac{\mathfrak{p}}{L/K}) = (\frac{\mathfrak{p}}{F/K})$ for some bijective function $f : Gal(L/K) \to Gal(F/K)$. It means $f$ is an isomorphism and $F= L$ because $F/K,L/K$ are abelian (looking at $E = FL,Gal(E/L),Gal(E/F)$).

Comment: I don't understand why this was closed. As the opening line (and the red text) says, I'm looking to understand a particular proof, not just why the statement is true. If the question is reopened, the deleted answer should perhaps be undeleted as well.

Comment: @rogerl I don't even understand why the answer was deleted (by a moderator...) it doesn't seem to contain any toxic material